# Double click on a file to launch python to edit it

Tags: python-3.x, file, file-handling

I can create a basic python script to open file and edit its content.
I want to know if we can use python such that if we double click on a txt file, the python program starts to execute for that file. It might take the path of the file or somehow, I just want it to edit the contents of that file.
I have no clue how to do it. I won't mind create something like a installer that installs on a system (actually thinking about it, a installer is quite preferable)

For example, a file has:

```
Name
Phone
Address
```

Now I want that if I just double click on it, the file opens in a python script and runs, which replaces Name, Phone and Address with some other data, but on the same file.

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: Windows 10, Linux mint...